# How to Create more than one type(table) in single Index(db) using Java API in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am in the process of learning elasticsearch using java api

I want to create two or more types with different mappings in elasticsearch using the java api.

how to create more than one type in same index in elastic search in java api ?

the code i tried is :

To create the index named "alpha". the below is working fine.

```
CreateIndexResponse cr =  (ts.admin().indices().prepareCreate("alpha").setSource(*getMapping_simple().string()*, XContentType.JSON).execute().actionGet());
```

the mapping of the type simple in index is in "getMapping_simple().string()" :

```
 {"mappings":{"simple":{"properties":{"id":{"type":"long"},"message":{"type":"text"}}}}}
```

now after this i want to create a new mapping and new type with nae complex

```
client.admin().indices().
        preparePutMapping("alpha", "complex_doc").
        setSource(*getMapping_complex().string()*, XContentType.JSON).
        execute().actionGet()
```

the mapping of the type complex_doc (the new type):

```
***{"mappings":{"complex_doc":{"properties":{"id":{"type":"long"},"name":{"type":"text"},"phNo":{"type":"text"},"weight":{"type":"float"},"height":{"type":"float"}}}}}***
```

the above gives me an error that

> Exception in thread "main" MapperParsingException[Root mapping
>   definition has unsupported parameters:  [mappings :
>   {complex_doc={properties={id={type=long}, name={type=text},
>   phNo={type=text}, weight={type=float}, height={type=float}}}}]]   at
>
> > org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.checkNoRemainingFields(DocumentMapperParser.java:151)
> >         at
> >     org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parse(DocumentMapperParser.java:139)
> >         at
> >     org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parse(DocumentMapperParser.java:91)
> >         at
> >     org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.parse(MapperService.java:729)
> >         at
> >     org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataMappingService$PutMappingExecutor.applyRequest(MetaDataMappingService.java:264)
> >         at
> >     org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataMappingService$PutMappingExecutor.execute(MetaDataMappingService.java:230)
> >         at
> >     org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService.executeTasks(MasterService.java:640)
> >         at
> >     org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService.calculateTaskOutputs(MasterService.java:270)
> >         at
> >     org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService.runTasks(MasterService.java:195)
> >         at
> >     org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService$Batcher.run(MasterService.java:130)
> >         at
> >     org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.TaskBatcher.runIfNotProcessed(TaskBatcher.java:150)
> >         at
> >     org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.TaskBatcher$BatchedTask.run(TaskBatcher.java:188)
> >         at
> >     org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:568)
> >         at
> >     org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.runAndClean(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:247)
> >         at
> >     org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:210)
> >         at
> >     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> >         at
> >     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> >         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748
>
> )

Answer (score 0):

**In 6.0 this multiple types for an index has been deleted!!!**

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/breaking-changes-6.0.html